# How to write current time from IOS on BLE

Tags: ios

I could not found anywhere how to write current time from IOS on BLE if any have any suggestion please answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement this and it will work my side,

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var comp = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second, .weekday, .nanosecond], from: date)
let milisecond = comp.nanosecond!/1000000
let quiterValue = milisecond/256
let year_mso = comp.year! & 0xFF
let year_lso = (comp.year! >> 8) & 0xFF
let ajjust_reason = 1

let timeZone = calendar.component(.timeZone, from: date)
let DSTZoon = Calendar.current.timeZone.isDaylightSavingTime()

let Year_MSO = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(year_mso))
let Year_LSO = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(year_lso))
let MONTH = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.month!))
let DAY = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.day!))
let HOUR = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.hour!))
let MINUTE = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.minute!))
let SECOND = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.second!))
let WEEKDAY = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(comp.weekday!))
let QUITERVALUE = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(quiterValue))
let AJRSON = Int8(bitPattern: UInt8(ajjust_reason))
```

//Current Time Write on tag

```
let currentTimeArray = [Year_MSO, Year_LSO, MONTH, DAY ,HOUR ,MINUTE ,SECOND_BYTE , WEEKDAY , QUITERVALUE , AJRSON];
let currentTimeArray_data = NSData(bytes: currentTimeArray, length: currentTimeArray.length)
if Device.Current_Time != nil {
        deviceValue.peripheral.writeValue(currentTimeArray_data as Data, for:    GrillRightDevice.Current_Time!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
func setTime(){

let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
self.deviceCurrentTime = "\(month)/\(day)/\(year) \(hour):\(minutes)"

var timeInterval:Int = Int(date.timeIntervalSince1970)

let data = NSData(bytes: &timeInterval, 
          length:MemoryLayout<Int>.size)//df799159

let sendData:Data = data as Data

self.selectPeripheral.writeValue(sendData, for: 
self.writeChar, type: .withResponse)//for set date & time

}
```